# Is linux packet update server connection secured?

Tags: linux, rpm, yum, apt

I'm distributing custom applications for redhat. I want to set up my update server to have the client applications auto-updated. I need the update process to be secured.

Can the connection to the update server secured and certified ?
Is there an encrypted update method ? With server certificate check ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS is a decently secure method. But your packages should be signed regardless.

Comment: How does the packet manager knows the packet dependencies before downloading them ? There is no database query ?